# Remove embeded newline character in a big query table column using a function

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a big query table with a column that has embedded new line character. I want to remove it using a function. It has to be a done using function and I cannot use properties like allowQuotedNewlines etc. I tried below and it is not working. Appreciate your help here.

```
select replace(column,'\\n','') from table
```

Comment: Your use of `REPLACE` function looks correct to me. Can you elaborate more on what is not working? And are you sure that it is the new line character that still remains?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without seeing your SQL or the error, it's hard to know what you're doing wrong. But `REPLACE` works just fine for me:

```
SELECT
  new_line_delims,
  REPLACE(new_line_delims, '\\n', '') AS new_line_delims_replaced
FROM (
  SELECT
    '\\nThis has several embedded\\n new line delims\\n' AS new_line_delims)
```

Comment: For some reason when I tried with out the escape character it is working. Thanks for your help

Comment: Great. Can you please accept the answer and also consider upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Just use one slash to escape, try this in the query window:

select '\r', '\n'